# openACC codes inside of the kernels directive sometimes works wrong

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, openacc

I am working on this simple code pieces
By the way i initialized all elements of c array with 0.

```
#pragma acc kernels copyin(a[0:n],b[0:n]), copyout(c[0:n])
{
  c[0]=11;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(c[i]==11) c[i]=123;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  }
}
```

I saw that c[0] was assigned at the host code pieces(CPU) when i looked the generated codelet. This means for iterations works with old c value(initialized value is 0). Therefore iterations never entered c[i]=123 assignment. I mean the code returned wrong results :( 
Have you encountered anything like it ever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [OpenACC v1.0 reference](http://www.openacc.org/sites/default/files/OpenACC_API_QuickRefGuide.pdf), the *acc kernels* directive surrounds loops to be executed on the accelerator, typically as a sequence of kernel operations.
This means that code outside loops does not necessarily have to run in parallel in the accelerator.
In your case, it would be better to use the *acc parallel* directive:

```
#pragma acc parallel copyin(a[0:n],b[0:n]), copyout(c[0:n])
{
  c[0]=11;
  #pragma acc loop 
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(c[i]==11) c[i]=123;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  }
}
```

The *acc loop* directive ensures that the iterations of the loop are distributed across the accelerator threads.

Comment: Thank you Ruyk for answer. But that case is little bit strange, isn't it? Well when Can we say kernels directive only parallelize iterations?

Comment: Well, to be slightly more precise, we could say that the Kernels directive creates a number of kernels from the annotated loop nests contained in the region. However this behaviour may change depending on the implementation or other optimizations the compiler may perform...